# 1D barcode can be generated with R?

Tags: r

Is there a R package for this? I´m looking for something similar to [`qrencoder`](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/qrencoder) but in 1D

For now, my walkaround solution is to use `python-barcode` through `reticulate` but I would like to use a R library.

```
library(reticulate)

barcode <- import("barcode")
name  <- barcode$generate('EAN13', '7750243002455', output='barcode_svg')
```

My ultimate goal is to show barcodes of my products on a Shiny app

Comment: What are your inputs, and what sort of barcode (there are loads) do you need? Even some python code showing how you use python-barcode would help.

Comment: @Spacedman I have added some code as you asked for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [zintr](https://github.com/CannaData/zintr) package, which uses [zint](http://www.zint.org.uk).

```
barcode_print(8675309, "barcode1.png")
```

[image]